# My new Nintendo Switch Lite battery dies fast

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-lite

I've got a Nintendo Switch Lite Dialga & Palkia edition, I've got it yesterday. I downloaded Fortnite and started playing it, everything was normal at first but then the battery started to die fast.

I don't know anything about Nintendo Switch Lite.
How do I slow the battery?

Comment: how long did you play it before it started dying fast?

Answer (score 7):

According to the article
[Nintendo Switch OLED battery life tested - here’s how it stacks up](https://www.tomsguide.com/features/nintendo-switch-oled-battery-life-tested),
the battery of the Nintendo Switch Lite should last for more than 3 hours
when playing a demanding video game.

If your battery only lasts minutes, then it is defective.
You need to replace the battery, or even replace the entire
Nintendo Switch Lite.

Ask for support from the vendor, and demand replacement or reimbursement.

Comment: It is basically that and nothing else. There is clearly something very wrong with your brand new switch lasts minutes. Fortnite might be a very intensive game (graphics and always online) but really, it should not last 'minutes'. It should last at least an hour or even more.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Where does "minutes" come from? Comments on the original question on SuperUser?

Comment: Yeah, I can play games like "The show 22" (demanding because of how realistic it is) and NBA 2k 22 (again, realistic) and especially fortnite for hours on end without getting even a battery warning. Admittedly, I use the regular switch and not the lite, so it's different but still.